# db2 get sequence value different with value get through application

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, sequence, increment

I found a weird incident in my application and db2.

I created a sequence as follow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE MY.CSAUDITTRAIL_SEQ AS BIGINT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 10 NO MAXVALUE CYCLE ORDER;
```

And I have a table as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE MY.CHANNELSERVICEAUDITTRAIL ( 
  "CSAUDITID" BIGINT NOT NULL , 
  "LOGINID" BIGINT , 
  "CREATED" TIMESTAMP , CONSTRAINT "CHANNELSERVICEAUDITTRAIL_PK" PRIMARY KEY ( "CSAUDITID" ) 
);
```

In my CHANNELSERVICEAUDITTRAIL entity class, I have something as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "MY")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CSAUDITTRAIL_SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 500, sequenceName = "MY.CSAUDITTRAIL_SEQ", schema = "MY")
public class ChannelServiceAuditTrail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CSAUDITTRAIL_SEQ")
    private long csAuditId;
```

And I am using `org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl` to do the persist and flush in my `DataAccessBean` layer:

```
@Override
public T persistAndFlush(T entity) {
    getEm().persist(entityClass.cast(entity));
    getEm().flush();
    return entity;
}
```

As my understanding, every time I persist and flush my `ChannelServiceAuditTrail` entity, the `csAuditId` value will get from CSAUDITTRAIL_SEQ, and increase by 10 every time.

But the output is different as what I see, when I use the following query to get the sequence value, the value will increase by 10 every time, for example, the current value is 19881

```
select next value for tibs.CSAUDITTRAIL_SEQ from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

However, in my application, when I debug or put log under the `getEm().persist(entityClass.cast(entity));`, I found that the value is different, not 19881, but its 19302 and increase by 1 every time.

I am wondering how could this happen, is it some rule that I miss out for db2 sequence?

Comment: Why do you have "allocationSize = 500"  when the underlying sequence has "INCREMENT BY 10" ?

Comment: please read this post: https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/52096666.html